# Sphere with DirectX 11

Tags: c++, math, 3d, directx-11

I try to create a basic sphere with DirectX 11. See below for code. But some points have an incorrect z-value. I correct them at the end of the code manually.

I rather not correct them manually, but have the math working correctly. I do not see what is wrong. Can any one else see it?

```
void CreateSphere(std::vector<EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color>& Vertex_Color_Vector_Out, std::vector<unsigned short>& us_Indices_Vector_Out)
{
    int int_Factor = 10;
    float flt_Radius = 10.0f;
    float flt_XT1, flt_YT1, flt_ZT1, flt_XT2, flt_YT2, flt_ZT2;
    int iPos = 0;
    UINT ui_ShapeCount = int_Factor * int_Factor * 2;
    Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.clear();
    us_Indices_Vector_Out.clear();
    std::vector<float> flt_Vector_PosX;
    std::vector<float> flt_Vector_PosY;
    std::vector<float> flt_Vector_PosZ;
    for (int i = 0; i < int_Factor * int_Factor; i++)
    {
        flt_Vector_PosX.push_back(0.0f);
        flt_Vector_PosY.push_back(0.0f);
        flt_Vector_PosZ.push_back(0.0f);
    }
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < int_Factor; j++)
    {
        FLOAT theta = (DirectX::XM_PI * j) / (int_Factor);

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < int_Factor; i++)
        {
            iPos = j * int_Factor + i;
            FLOAT phi = (2 * DirectX::XM_PI * i) / (int_Factor);
            flt_Vector_PosX[iPos] = ((float)(sin(theta) * cos(phi))) * flt_Radius;
            flt_Vector_PosY[iPos] = ((float)(sin(theta) * sin(phi))) * flt_Radius;
            flt_Vector_PosZ[iPos] = ((float)(cos(theta))) * flt_Radius;
        }
    }
    int iNext = 0;
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < int_Factor; j++)
    {

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < int_Factor; i++)
        {
            if (i == int_Factor - 1)
                iNext = 0;
            else iNext = i + 1;

            iPos = (j * int_Factor * 6) + (i * 6);

            Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_Vector_PosX[j * int_Factor + i], flt_Vector_PosY[j * int_Factor + i], flt_Vector_PosZ[j * int_Factor + i],
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
            us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos);

            flt_XT1 = flt_Vector_PosX[j * int_Factor + iNext];
            flt_YT1 = flt_Vector_PosY[j * int_Factor + iNext];
            flt_ZT1 = flt_Vector_PosZ[j * int_Factor + iNext];
            Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_XT1, flt_YT1, flt_ZT1,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
            us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 1);

            if (j != int_Factor - 1)
            {
                flt_XT2 = flt_Vector_PosX[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + i];
                flt_YT2 = flt_Vector_PosY[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + i];
                flt_ZT2 = flt_Vector_PosZ[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + i];
            }
            else
            {
                flt_XT2 = 0;
                flt_YT2 = 0;
                flt_ZT2 = -1;
            }
            Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_XT2, flt_YT2, flt_ZT2,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
            us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 2);

            Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_XT2, flt_YT2, flt_ZT2,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
            us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 3);

            Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_XT1, flt_YT1, flt_ZT1,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
            us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 4);

            if (j != int_Factor - 1)
            {
                Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ flt_Vector_PosX[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + iNext], flt_Vector_PosY[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + iNext], flt_Vector_PosZ[((j + 1) * int_Factor) + iNext],
                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
                us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 5);
            }
            else
            {
                Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.push_back(EJM_DGE::Vertex_Color{ 0, 0, -1,
                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // = color.
                us_Indices_Vector_Out.push_back(iPos + 5);
            }
        }
    }
    // Some z values are incorrect. They are near the origin.
    for (int i = 542; i <= 599; i += 3)
    {
        Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.at(i).z = -flt_Radius;
    }
    for (int i = 543; i <= 599; i += 6)
    {
        Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.at(i).z = -flt_Radius;
        Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.at(i).z = -flt_Radius;
        Vertex_Color_Vector_Out.at(i).z = -flt_Radius;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: Without the rendering code, it's really hard to know what the problem really is. That said, you should look at ``GeometricPrimitive`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: Ok ty I will check it out.